# simulate onvaluechange event for Picker with enzyme

Tags: react-native, enzyme, jestjs

I am trying to test onValueChange for a Picker I implemented using Jest and Enzyme and I am not sure if I am doing it the right way.

my component:

```
const ManufacturersPicker = ({
   Manufacturers,
   ManufacturersPickerOnValueChange,
   selectedManufacturerId,
}) => {
  const ManufacturersPickerItems = [];
  ManufacturersPickerItems.push(Manufacturers.map(item => (
  <Picker.Item
    label={item.manufacturer}
    value={item.manufactureId}
  />)));

  return (
    <Picker
        selectedValue={selectedManufacturerId}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
        ManufacturersPickerOnValueChange(itemValue, itemIndex)}
        mode="dialog"
    >
        {ManufacturersPickerItems}
    </Picker>
  );
};
```

and my test is as follows

```
const manufacturersPickerOnValueChange = jest.fn();
const valueChangeEvent = {target: {value: 1, index: 0}};
const tree = shallow(<ManufacturersPicker
        Manufacturers={manufacturers}
        ManufacturersPickerOnValueChange={manufacturersPickerOnValueChange}
        selectedManufacturerId={1}/>);
tree.find('Picker').simulate('onValueChange', valueChangeEvent);
expect(manufacturersPickerOnValueChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(manufacturersPickerOnValueChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1,0);
```

I keep getting an error indicating that the jest function hasnt been called

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.
```

I am not sure if it is the event I am passing which is wrong or the finding a wrong element.

Comment: did my advice work for you?

Comment: yes it did. Is there a reference for what values to pass to simulate method ?

Comment: I have used it like this: .simulate('ValueChange', 'newValue'). You can just give the new value which would be picked from Picker instead of passing that target Object. I guess in your case it would be .simulate('ValueChange', '1')

Comment: Sorry I was more interested in how you knew to pass "ValueChange" and not 'onValueChange" to the function. Is there a reference for what the first argument takes ?

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean. I have not seen any reference on how to use simulate, but it is really easy. Lets say you have component which has 'onPress' as a prop. Then you would simulate it with  .simulate('Press'). So what ever you try to simulate, just drop the 'on' - prefix and it should work.

Comment: actually there's the reference you might be looking for: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.md

Comment: Thanks for your tip on removing the 'on' prefix. That was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line:

```
tree.find('Picker').simulate('onValueChange', valueChangeEvent);
```

to this:

```
tree.find('Picker').simulate('ValueChange', valueChangeEvent);
```